# mp3 file shows incorrect duration after merging two different files into one

Tags: c#, mp3

I recently made a tool which is supposed to merge downloaded mp3 files together. It works just fine, except on some files. When I open the merged mp3 sometimes, I see the length of the file, but it just kept playing beyond the supposed end.

I realized it might not be a constant bitrate, but when looking in the properties of both of the files, it says 96kbps for each of them. I also thought it could be the ID3v1 and ID3v2 tags, which I removed, but still came to the same problem.

Does anyone know how I can change the file to show the correct file length? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

MP3 files have no duration specified inside them.  They're just a series of MPEG frames, and the headers don't indicate anything beyond what's in each frame.

Players will guess at the duration based on the bitrate and file size.  However, the bitrate can vary.  Even though you checked the properties of each file and see 96 kbps, it's possible that one of those files is VBR.  Most of the time, player software will tell you the bitrate based on the first frame and not beyond that.

The only way to actually know the duration is to read and parse each frame header.  Some players will do this, but not all.

As you've guessed, there are also some ID3 tags that can hint at duration, but these aren't always used.